# MeteorJS, is it possible to change PORT on windows with environment?

Tags: windows, meteor

I'm trying to run 2 Meteor applications on one laptop under Windows 8.1.
I use environment variables to setup the application. It works for mongourl, rooturl, packagedirs, but the port variable seems to be unused by meteor.

I set PORT using this in my console :

> set PORT=3002

but meteor doesn't seem to use it.
I have a workaround using port parameter like this :

> meteor --port 3002

Is it possible to use environment variable "port" with windows ?

Comment: Can you please include the steps you did and what errors shown up?

Comment: running 2nd meteor app via `meteor -p 3002` on 2nd command prompt works fine for me. If you put details, that may help to solve your issue

Comment: yes in fact if i use port parameter it works, but i want to use environment settings, and it fails. here is a link to a reproducable steps : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4413#issuecomment-123057340